# Changing colors on RGB lcd using PWM

Tags: python, rgb, sensors, pwm

I was wondering on how should I approach the PWM output and alternate each sensor reading on the LCD. I recently just changed it. I could get a reading for each sensor, but when the entered limit was reached no changes were made in the PWM. The code I pasted below is the new approach I was going for`enter code here`. Would I have to make a class?

Also the code previous to this that was working was the same, but each sensor LCD display was at the end of the code.

```
`import os
import glob
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO   # IMPORT GPIOS
import time               # IMPORT CURRENT TIME
from RPLCD import CharLCD, BacklightMode       # IMPORT LCD DISPLAY CODE
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

lcd = CharLCD(cols = 16, rows=2, pin_rs=26,pin_e=24,pins_data=[22,32,36,37])

# SET OUTPUTS
GPIO.setup(29,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(31,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(33,GPIO.OUT)


# Set frequency limits
RED = GPIO.PWM(29,100)
GREEN = GPIO.PWM(31,100)
BLUE = GPIO.PWM(33,100)

# High Temperature Limits
tHIGHroom1 = input('Enter High Limit for room 1: ')
tHIGHroom2 = input('Enter High Limit for room 2: ')
tHIGHroom3 = input('Enter High Limit for room 3: ')

# Low Temperature Limits
tLOWroom1 = input('Enter Low Limit for room 1: ')
tLOWroom2 = input('Enter Low Limit for room 2: ')
tLOWroom3 = input('Enter Low Limit for room 3: ')

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

# DEFINE EACH SENSOR
temp_sensor1 = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000075f7386/w1_slave' # CHANGE DEVICE ID IF NEEDED
temp_sensor2 = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000075ffa1b/w1_slave'
temp_sensor3 = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000744d665/w1_slave'

while True:

 def temp_raw():
        f = open(temp_sensor1, 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return lines
 def read_temp():
        lines = temp_raw()
        while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
                time.sleep(0.2)
                lines = temp_raw()
        temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
        if temp_output != -1:
               temp_string = lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
               temp_c = int(temp_string) / 1000.0
               temp_f1 = temp_c * 9 / 5 +32
               temp_f1 = str(round(temp_f1,1))
               return temp_f1
def sesor1():
    value1 = read_temp()
    if value1 >= tHIGHroom1:
           RED.start(70)
           GREEN.start(100)
           BLUE.start(100)
           return none
    if value1 <= tLOWroom1:
           RED.start(100)
           GREEN.start(100)
           BLUE.start(60)
           return none
    if tLOWrooom1 <= value1 <= tHIGHroom1:
           RED.start(0)
           GREEN.start(50)
           BLUE.start(50)
           return none

     lcd.cursor_pos = (0,0)
     lcd.write_string("Room1: "+read_temp()+unichr(223))
     lcd.cursor_pos = (1,0)
     lcd.write_string("Hi:" + str(tHIGHroom1) + " Lo:" + str(tLOWroom1))
     time.sleep(4)
     RED.stop()
     GREEN.stop()
     BLUE.stop()
     lcd.clear()


 def temp_rawr():
        f = open(temp_sensor2, 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return lines

 def read_tempr():
        lines = temp_rawr()
        while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
                time.sleep(0.2)
                lines = temp_rawr()
        temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
        if temp_output != -1:
               temp_string = lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
               temp_c = int(temp_string) / 1000.0
               temp_f2 = temp_c * 9 / 5 +32
               temp_f2 = str(round(temp_f2,1))
               return temp_f2

 def sensor2():
    value2 = read_tempr()
    if value2 >= tHIGHroom2:
               RED.start(70)
               GREEN.start(100)
               BLUE.start(100)
               return none
    if value2 <= tLOWroom2:
               RED.start(100)
               GREEN.start(100)
               BLUE.start(60)
               return none
    if tLOWrooom2 <= value2 <= tHIGHroom2:
               RED.start(0)
               GREEN.start(50)
               BLUE.start(50)
               return none

               lcd.cursor_pos = (0,0)
               lcd.write_string("Room2: "+read_tempr()+unichr(223))
               lcd.cursor_pos = (1,0)
               lcd.write_string("Hi:" + str(tHIGHroom2) + " Lo:" + str(tLOWroom2))
               time.sleep(4)
               RED.stop()
               GREEN.stop()
               BLUE.stop()
               lcd.clear()


 def temp_rawx():
        f = open(temp_sensor3, 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close() n
        return lines

 def read_tempx():
        lines = temp_rawx()
        while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
                time.sleep(0.2)
                lines = temp_rawx()
        temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
        if temp_output != -1:
               temp_string = lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
               temp_c = int(temp_string) / 1000.0
               temp_f3 = temp_c * 9 / 5 +32
               temp_f3 = str(round(temp_f3,1))
               return temp_f3
 def sensor3():
    value3 = read_tempx()
    if value3 >= tHIGHroom3:
               RED.start(70)
               GREEN.start(100)
               BLUE.start(100)
               return none
    if value3 <= tLOWroom3:
               RED.start(100)
               GREEN.start(100)
               BLUE.start(60)
               return none
    if tLOWrooom3 <= value3 <= tHIGHroom3:
               RED.start(0)
               GREEN.start(50)
               BLUE.start(50)
               return none

               lcd.cursor_pos = (0,0)
               lcd.write_string("Room3: "+read_temp()+unichr(223))
               lcd.cursor_pos = (1,0)
               lcd.write_string("Hi:" + str(tHIGHroom3) + " Lo:" + str(tLOWroom3))
               time.sleep(4)
               RED.stop()
               GREEN.stop()
               BLUE.stop()
               lcd.clear()`
```